# How can I add key and values from one object into each object in an array via jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I'm using jolt and I have an input object where I would like to take the keys out of one property and insert them into each object of an array in another property:

My input:

```json
{
  "jolt_marketplaceMetadata": {
    "NAN_KEY": 1,
    "TEMP": 3
  },
  "jolt_attributes": [
    {
      "name": "HELLO",
      "yyup": 3
    },
    {
      "huh": "please",
      "work": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

The result I'm aiming for:

```json
 "jolt_attributes": [
    {
      "name": "HELLO",
      "yyup": 3,
      "NAN_KEY": 1,
      "TEMP": 3
    },
    {
      "huh": "please",
      "work": 2,
      "NAN_KEY": 1,
      "TEMP": 3
    }
  ]
```

I've tried a couple of different spec arrays and I've gotten pretty close, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the values in without merging all of the data from each of the objects in the array:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "jolt_attributes": {
        "*": {
          "*": "jolt_attributes[&1].&",
          "@(2,jolt_marketplaceMetadata)": "jolt_attributes[&1]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

which gives me:

```json
{
  "jolt_attributes": [
    {
      "NAN_KEY": 1,
      "TEMP": 3,
      "name": "HELLO",
      "yyup": 3,
      "huh": "please",
      "work": 2
    },
    {
      "NAN_KEY": 1,
      "TEMP": 3,
      "name": "HELLO",
      "yyup": 3,
      "huh": "please",
      "work": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

It adds the keys from jolt_marketplaceMetadata, but it also merges all of the key/values from each of the array objects together each time.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "jolt_attributes": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2[#2].&",
          "@2,jolt_marketplaceMetadata.NAN_KEY": "&2[#2].NAN_KEY",
          "@2,jolt_marketplaceMetadata.TEMP": "&2[#2].TEMP"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where

- &2 replicates the key of the array (`"jolt_attributes"`)
- [#2] loops through the indexes of that array after traversing the
  tree 2 levels(once for colon, once for opening curly brace) and generates arraywise(*array of objects* here) result

You can even make it more dynamic by using the following spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*attributes": {
        "*": {
          "@2,jolt_marketplaceMetadata": { "*": "&3[&1].&" }, // &3 represents going two levels up the tree to get the literal "jolt_attributes"
          "*": "&2[&1].&" // &2 represents going two levels up the tree to get the literal "jolt_attributes"; [&1] stands for bringing the values of the indexes of the "jolt_attributes" in array-wise manner.  
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help!! And thanks for the additional explanation. It makes sense once you describe it, but I def couldn't see it when reading back through the jolt code docs. :clap: :bows: