# How to dynamically add key and values from one object into another object in an array via jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I'm using jolt and I have an input object where I would like to take the keys out of one property and insert them into each object of an array in another property dynamically:

My input:

```
{
  "data": {
    "NAN_KEY": 1,
    "TEMP": 3
  },
  "attributes": [
    {
      "name": "attribute1",
      "value": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "attribute2",
      "value": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

The result I'm aiming for:

```
 "attributes": [
    {
      "name": "attribute1",
      "value": 3,
      "NAN_KEY": 1,
      "TEMP": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "attribute2",
      "value": 2,
      "NAN_KEY": 1,
      "TEMP": 3
    }
  ]
```

This question was posted previously in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75415772/how-can-i-add-key-and-values-from-one-object-into-each-object-in-an-array-via-jo)

But after using the solution, I realized I needed it to dynamically add the entire object instead of hardcoding the fields

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to make it more dynamic such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "attributes": {
        "*": {
          "@2,data": { "*": "[&1].&" }, // go two levels up the tree to grab the values of the "data" array
          "*": "[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! this will help a bunch

Comment: Hi @PeterMassarello , nice to hear that will help. Kindly you can mark as the answer.