# How to take two lists and add all the elements of one list to each element of the other

Tags: json, jolt

I made a post a bit ago that talked about a similar problem, but this time it is two lists instead of a list and an object. I tried adapting the jolt given in that solution but I am unable to figure anything substantial out.

I also need to create a new entry per each element in the first list

My input:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "NAN_KEY": 1,
      "TEMP": 3
    },
    {
      "NAN_KEY": 123,
      "TEMP": 1243523
    }
  ],
  "attributes": [
    {
      "name": "attribute1",
      "value": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "attribute2",
      "value": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

result I'm aiming for

```
{
"attributes": [
    {
      "name": "attribute1",
      "value": 3,
      "NAN_KEY": 1,
      "TEMP": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "attribute1",
      "value": 3,
      "NAN_KEY": 123,
      "TEMP": 1243523
    },
    {
      "name": "attribute2",
      "value": 2,
      "NAN_KEY": 1,
      "TEMP": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "attribute2",
      "value": 2,
      "NAN_KEY": 123,
      "TEMP": 1243523
    },
  ]
}
```

I need each attribute to have a new entry per each entry in data.
The previous solution can be found here! [How to dynamically add key and values from one object into another object in an array via jolt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75451057/how-to-dynamically-add-key-and-values-from-one-object-into-another-object-in-an)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the similar logic within the second spec in the following, after having matched within the first one such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "@2,attributes": {
            "*": "&1.attributes[&]"
          },
          "*": {
            "@": "&2.&3.&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {// accumulate under common nodes
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "attributes": {
          "*": {
            "@2,data": { "*": "&3.&4.&1.&" }, // go two levels up the tree to grab the values of the "data" array
            "*": "&2.&3.&1.&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {// get rid of object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "attributes": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2" // obtain the resulting array's name as "attributes"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]